# In IE 10 cursor not changing on hover

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I have a `<div>` for which cursor is set as

```
.TextBox:hover{
    cursor : move;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div tabindex="5" id="5" class="TextBox" style="display: block; font-size: 74.5833%;padding: 8px;">
        <div class="contentWrapper" style="border: 1px dotted rgb(147, 147, 147); cursor: text;">   
            <div class="contentEditor ElementToTransform" tabindex="1">     
                <div contenteditable="true" id="" class="contentEditorDiv"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

In all the browsers including IE 11 it's working fine, but only in IE 10 its displaying the normal pointer.

**Can somebody help? I can't reproduce the issue on Fiddle, the div is part of much bigger web application, and something is causing issue on IE 10. I tried every thing mentioned in the answers but nothing has worked so far.**

Comment: can you give the html also

Comment: @ManjunathSiddappa added html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Atlast I figured out the issue. For

```
.TextBox
```

I had set

```
background-color : transparent !important;
```

changing it to

```
background-color:rgba(255, 255, 255,0) !important;
```

fixed the issue. Looks like IE 10 has mouse pointer issues if we use `transparent` directly.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure it will work in IE 10, because i dont have it.

Tested in IE 9, it is working like a Charm!

Try this fiddle

**http://jsfiddle.net/xz5kyggr/5/**

```
<div tabindex="5" id="5" class="TextBox" onmouseover="this.style.cursor='move'" > 
Link  to wait
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code i hope it will solve your problem, if its not working please provide the html

```
.TextBox *:hover{
    cursor : wait !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

cursor:progress; does the same cursor for me in chrome. You might try that.